# Latex beginner need suggestion?

Tags: beamer, presentations

I was just a beginner in using Latex, can anyone suggest me from where I can get list of different commands to be generally used in the case of presentations and make various changes in them according to our need ?

Comment: Just search for "latex beginner guides" or maybe "latex beamer beginner guides" on the internet.

Answer (score 3):

For general help with TeX, I would recommend visiting TeX Users Group page http://tug.org/begin.html.

<plug>
Also, if you are serious into TeX, please consider joining TUG!
</plug>

After you installed TeX, `texdoc beamer` gives you a very good introduction into presentations and their customization.

Comment: I am not sure this is appropriate here.